# Which roads in Mexico have tolls and how high are they

Tags: driving, mexico, tolls

Mexico has an extensive network of roads including highways. Which of these roads have tolls and how high are they?

Comment: What part of Mexico?  There are a lot of toll roads with differing charges, around $1-2 MXN per kilometer of toll road (between plazas)

Comment: I'm mostly interested in Jukatan, Campeche, Tabasco and Quintana Roo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Secretaría de Comunicaciones y Transportes website has a list of all toll-roads (Autopistas), their length, and toll charges.  As mentioned in my comment, the toll is approximately $1-2MXN per kilometer of toll road between plazas.

[Información de las Vías](http://app.sct.gob.mx/sibuac_internet/ControllerUI?action=cmdDatosOperRep&countVias=158&radioSel=1&selectVia=193&selectVia=196&selectVia=1&selectVia=209&selectVia=4&selectVia=227&selectVia=5&selectVia=19&selectVia=7&selectVia=9&selectVia=10&selectVia=240&selectVia=12&selectVia=13&selectVia=14&selectVia=16&selectVia=115&selectVia=18&selectVia=218&selectVia=20&selectVia=243&selectVia=21&selectVia=22&selectVia=23&selectVia=118&selectVia=8&selectVia=195&selectVia=25&selectVia=26&selectVia=27&selectVia=28&selectVia=29&selectVia=30&selectVia=6&selectVia=251&selectVia=32&selectVia=33&selectVia=224&selectVia=35&selectVia=36&selectVia=237&selectVia=244&selectVia=231&selectVia=233&selectVia=37&selectVia=212&selectVia=225&selectVia=176&selectVia=177&selectVia=199&selectVia=247&selectVia=39&selectVia=205&selectVia=250&selectVia=256&selectVia=48&selectVia=245&selectVia=40&selectVia=217&selectVia=241&selectVia=238&selectVia=249&selectVia=42&selectVia=43&selectVia=259&selectVia=45&selectVia=246&selectVia=230&selectVia=49&selectVia=51&selectVia=52&selectVia=54&selectVia=55&selectVia=56&selectVia=57&selectVia=58&selectVia=252&selectVia=59&selectVia=219&selectVia=203&selectVia=60&selectVia=61&selectVia=62&selectVia=215&selectVia=192&selectVia=65&selectVia=213&selectVia=66&selectVia=67&selectVia=68&selectVia=64&selectVia=69&selectVia=70&selectVia=72&selectVia=73&selectVia=74&selectVia=75&selectVia=76&selectVia=77&selectVia=254&selectVia=232&selectVia=214&selectVia=78&selectVia=79&selectVia=198&selectVia=80&selectVia=81&selectVia=162&selectVia=83&selectVia=84&selectVia=85&selectVia=87&selectVia=86&selectVia=88&selectVia=90&selectVia=91&selectVia=89&selectVia=92&selectVia=93&selectVia=229&selectVia=94&selectVia=95&selectVia=211&selectVia=96&selectVia=97&selectVia=210&selectVia=98&selectVia=99&selectVia=100&selectVia=101&selectVia=102&selectVia=103&selectVia=104&selectVia=106&selectVia=107&selectVia=31&selectVia=109&selectVia=110&selectVia=50&selectVia=228&selectVia=114&selectVia=242&selectVia=180&selectVia=111&selectVia=112&selectVia=200&selectVia=119&selectVia=207&selectVia=253&selectVia=204&selectVia=117&selectVia=120&selectVia=121&selectVia=122&selectVia=258&selectVia=123&selectVia=124&selectVia=125)

The roads are designated with a `D`, for example the free road from Tijuana to Ensenada is Route `1`, the toll road from Tijuana to Ensenada is `1D`.  The distance from the toll plaza at Playas Tijuana and the plaza at Rosarito is 26km and the toll is $46 MXN.